# Update values vs removing and updating entire record

Tags: sql

this is more of a general question I came across today.

To update an sql record I noticed that it is common practice where I work to store the old record values, remove the record, and then add a new record with the old values plus one or more values that have been changed.

Wouldn't it be easier to simply update only the values you want to edit? Or, is there some reason for the entire removal that I'm not seeing?

Thank you.

Comment: How is it related to C# at all?

Comment: Consider that the record has many related tables and you need to add/update/delete all children as well, then it's often easier just to delete the parent and [let the database delete also all children](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/) and create all from scratch. Then you only need to maintain one method.

Comment: @Tim, I thought it might be relevant since it's the language we're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a record, then just update it using update query. It's not a good practice to remove the entire row and inserting back after applying modification instead of an update query.